# global list empty when called in another function

Tags: javascript

I have defined a global list. I have a function that pushes values onto that list, this one works fine. However, I have another function, called after the function pushing the values is done, that needs the values from this list. Unfortunately, when I call the list in this last function, it shows as empty. Why is that?

simplified JS:

```
var recherche=[];

function clickUpdates() {

  
  switch(count) {
    // call recherche.push() multiple times
  }

function lancement_scraping() {
  
  console.log(recherche); //shows recherche as empty array


//window.close()
}
```

Comment: Did you call that `clickUpdates` function?

Comment: Can you do a code snippet since it is javascript ? It is much easier to reproduce the issue. https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/

Comment: Please provide a code that can reproduce the issue. Given code also there is a "}" missing.

Comment: Most likely you're calling `clickUpdates()` asynchronously, but calling `lancement_scraping()` before any of these async calls.